# chkdsk Windows 7 on notebook screen

Tags: laptop, display, chkdsk

Is there anyway I can run chkdsk on my windows 7 notebook without having my screen on durign the whole process?

I ask because I like running chkdsk while I'm sleeping... the problem is that the computer stays in the same room as I do, and having that blue screen light up the room during the wee hours of the night is not pleasant.

Comment: In power options set the lid-close trigger to "do nothing".

Comment: @techie007, you might as well put that in an answer box.

Comment: @techie007 Changed the setting and it works fine after boot, will check if this setting is preserved while chkdsk is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In many laptops there is a option to turn off screen which is usually associated with their Fn key and some Function key. See if your laptop have that too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fn key of my notebook doesn't work before the windows boot (where chkdsk happens), but I will check.